# MemoryMappedFiles namespace error

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I am getting The type or namespace name 'MemoryMappedFiles' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?) in asp.net c#. I am using framework 3.5.

Comment: but which assembly should i add that i dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CodeCaster said, looks like you are missing an assembly.

[`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class belongs on [`System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace and it is in *System.Core.dll* assembly.

For this, in the solution window, right click on "References" and choose "Add Reference.."  Go to the .NET tab, and double click on *System.Core.dll*.

> @SonerGönül I am using framework version 3.5

Then you should upgrade your .NET Framework version because `MemoryMappedFile` class added after .NET Framework 4.

[image]

Comment: but when I am adding System.Core dll, I am getting error that it could not be added because it is automatically referenced by build system.

Comment: Note that I looks like `MemoryMappedFile` was added in .NET 4. If you are targeting an earlier version of the framework, you won't be able to use this class. A solution--if possible--is to retarget your library against .NET 4 or later.

Comment: @MonikaParekh Are you sure you add this assembly to right project? And c45207 is right, `MemoryMappedFile` class added after .NET 4 version

Comment: So what should i do now?

Comment: @MonikaParekh What is the target .net version of your project?

Comment: @SonerGönül I am using framework version 3.5

Comment: @MonikaParekh As we said, you should upgrade your .net framework version since `MemoryMappedFile` was added after .NET Framework 4.

Comment: ok thanks i got solution.